# Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `exact`

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using "react-router-dom": "6.16.0". When I run my program it shows the warning:
react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `exact`.

```
If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: exact="true" or exact={value.toString()}.
     at a
     at LinkWithRef (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:39169:7)
     at NavLinkWithRef (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:39241:23)
     at div
     at Navigation (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1026:1)
     at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40942:15)
     at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:39057:5)
     at header
     at div
     at App
```

When Clicking on linewc leads to react-dom.development.js:86 It warns at the line:

```
Function.prototype.apply.call(console[level], console, argsWithFormat);
```

Does this error affect my program and how do I fix it?

Comment: Do you use `exact` anywhere in your code?

Answer (score 1):

The [`Link`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/link), and by extension [`NavLink`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/nav-link), component(s) haven't any `exact` prop in `react-router-dom@6`.

See [Link Source](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx#L497-L505)

> ```
> export interface LinkProps
>   extends Omit<React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>, "href"> {
>   reloadDocument?: boolean;
>   replace?: boolean;
>   state?: any;
>   preventScrollReset?: boolean;
>   relative?: RelativeRoutingType;
>   to: To;
> }
> ```

and [NavLink Source](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx#L604-L623)

> ```
> export interface NavLinkProps
>   extends Omit<LinkProps, "className" | "style" | "children"> {
>   children?:
>     | React.ReactNode
>     | ((props: { isActive: boolean; isPending: boolean }) => React.ReactNode);
>   caseSensitive?: boolean;
>   className?:
>     | string
>     | ((props: {
>         isActive: boolean;
>         isPending: boolean;
>       }) => string | undefined);
>   end?: boolean;
>   style?:
>     | React.CSSProperties
>     | ((props: {
>         isActive: boolean;
>         isPending: boolean;
>       }) => React.CSSProperties | undefined);
> }
> ```

The solution to fix the issue of an `exact`prop/attribute being written to the DOM is to simply remove it from whatever `NavLink` component that has it.

If you have a `NavLink` that links to a parent route, e.g. a route that has nested routes, e.g. sub-routes, then you can use the [`end`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/nav-link#end) prop.